# SQL Server Set Value of Select Max or Sum Into Variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I try to make a stored procedure on SQL Server but when I set the select results into one variable it returns NULL.

example:

```
set @myvar= select Sum(Values) from myTable
```

but when I make a select without a function, the variable returns the expected value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mixture of the two ways to set a variable here.

It should be either.

```
set @myvar = (select sum(Values) from myTable)
```

OR my preference would be

```
select @myvar = sum(Values) from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select @myvar = Sum(Values) from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax will be

```
SELECT @myvar= SUM(Values) FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I try both `set @myvar =...` and `select @myvar=...`  but dont work, as well i try `Select @myvar` in the end of query.

Is strange, when i try to assign one value without sum or max this return the expected value.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a SQL fiddle on sqlfiddle.com?